# What is now instead of spring-hibernate3.jar?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Last version of spring-hibernate3.jar was in 2008. What is now for example for `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hibernate support classes are in now `spring-orm.jar`.